# How could I add a way to add like a multiplier to make it so when i click an object it would make my score go up by a 5x multiplier?

Tags: javascript, code.org

So pretty much I'm trying to make a score/clicker game and I'm trying to make it so when I buy the upgrade it will multiply my score by however much I made the multiplier to. So if I had it giving me 5 points on click how could I make it so it would give me 25 points on click after buying the upgrade. (Upgrade would be making it a 5x multiplier). I can't figure out any ideas and would much appreciate any ideas thanks.

Edit: Im new to this and don't understand how to add code correctly but to better explain it I have an onEvent function that makes it so when I click my object it gives me 10 score and adds 10 to the score text display every click. Then my main function is of purchasing any items in the store I made. One purchase will give me a 5x multiplier another will give me a 10x multiplier. Im trying to figure out another function I can make that will set my multipliers in place when I buy them so they actually do something.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Actual Code = better than a description of code.

Comment: Sounds like you need something like `total = total + increase * multiplier`

Comment: @epascarello Okay i followed your suggestion and it kind of worked for me. I made it so after I buy the upgrade the next time I click I get the multiplier to work the first time. It normally goes up by 10 but after buying the multiplier I want it to go up by 50 on each click. After buying the upgrade it goes up by 50 the first time but then goes back to going up only by 10. Any idea how to keep it going up by 5x the amount each time instead of the first time?

Answer (score 0):

If what you wanted to do was multiply your current score by 5 and get points twice as fast you could do:

`totalScore = Score * multiplier` where `score += pointsGained` once every tick.

Multiplier is your multiplier, score is the amount of points you have earned, and `pointsGained` is the amount of points you gain each tick. `totalScore` is the score being displayed

If what you wanted to do was multiply the amount of points you get from now on by 5, you could do:

`totalScore = score` where `score += (pointsGained * Multiplier)` each tick.